# Why is a hand crossbow light if you need both hands to use it?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, ranged-attack, two-weapon-fighting

The hand crossbow has to properties, ammo, and light, but you need a free hand to load the crossbow so how is it light if you need both hands.

Answer (score 3):

## Loading ≠ making a ranged attack.

The *Player's Handbook* description of the *light* weapon property begins

> A light weapon is small and easy to handle, making it ideal for use when fighting with two weapons.

A loaded hand crossbow does not need two hands to *fire*. For example, see the text of the *crossbow expert* feat in the *Player's Handbook* :

> When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a <s>loaded</s> [since revised] hand crossbow you are holding.

Because the description *does not say* "you may drop or sheath your one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a loaded hand crossbow you are holding," and because it says "holding", the necessary implication is that you are making the crossbow attack with a single hand.

*Sage Advice* makes this distinction between firing and the loading aspect of the attack action explicit:

> **A hand crossbow is a one-handed weapon,** so it can, indeed, be used for both attacks, assuming you **have a hand free to load the hand crossbow between the two attacks.**